How to correctly setup logging in AWS Lamda with Python
I am currently struggling to set up some basic logging in AWS Lambda. I have a function created from a container image where the main.py file looks like this:
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    log_file = "/tmp/application.log"
    
    if os.path.exists(log_file):
        with open(log_file, "r") as f:
            file = f.read()
    else:
        file = "File does not exist"
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": file
    }

The logging configuration is created in another file, logging_config.py:
import logging

LOG_FILE = "/tmp/application.log"

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE),
        logging.StreamHandler(),
    ]
)

logger = logging.getLogger("my-logger")

The logger variable is then imported into other modules that should log on various levels (info, debug, error). However, I am not able to see the logs anywhere, nor do they get redirected to the /tmp/application.log file. When the function finishes executing, it returns:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": ""
}

So I am assuming that the log file gets created because the body is empty, but not populated with anything.
What I am missing? Thanks.
I tried the solution above but the logs were not redirected to the log file.

can you try with print statements?

Verify this outside of Lambda first e.g. on your local machine. Also be aware that Lambda functions have built-in logging to CloudWatch Logs and all you have to do is print something (be sure the Lambda function has at least AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole permissions).

I've tried it on my local machine by running the image and the main.py file. It works there, the logs do appear in the .log file.

@AlbinPaul you mean by redirecting the output of print statement to a file?

Why do you think /tmp/application.log is should be created?  The Lambda you've shown will never create one, so it's not surprising it's not created.

The logger is configured to log into that /tmp/application.log file. I believe the log file does get created because, as you can see in the lamda_handler function, I try to open and read from the file if it exists, else I return the string "File does not exist". Since my lamda function returns "body": "", I assumed the log file gets created with no logs written into it.

Verify that your other modules are actually calling logger.info() etc. and investigate whether or not you need to flush or shutdown the logger before retrieving the logs from file.

The easiest way to do logging is to simply print() information.
When running the Lambda function in the management console, messages will appear after using the Test function.
Also, any executions of the Lambda function will send these messages to CloudWatch Logs, which can be accessed via the Monitoring tab in the Lambda console. It will include information about when the function started and stopped, plus and messages that were printed during execution.
This way, you not need to change what is returned by the function itself.
Given that the Lambda environment is only temporary, this approach is much better than attempting to handle files on the local operating system, which can disappear after the function stops running.

Thanks for the info. To make it more clear, I am only interested in the log file for the execution lifetime of the function. Basic workflow is that some process starts, it should log to that file, the contents of that file are returned in the JSON response when the functions terminates. The fact that the lambda environment is temporary does not concern me because new logs will be produced with each execution.

How does logging_configuration.py get called?  When an AWS Lambda function is invoked, the lambda_handler() function is called, so you should either put the logging code there, or at the top of the main.py file (which is code that gets called once, when the Lambda function is first created).

Thanks for the suggestions. In the end, I moved away from the idea of configuring my own logging, and instead just used print statements and fetch the logs from Cloudwatch right before the function exits.
